# FieldInfo.CaptionStyle in custom form control not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, content-management-system, kentico

I have created a custom form control for use in my Kentico bizform using asp.net and I want to change the field caption style of another field in the form depending upon the value in my custom form control field. So, this is what I have done:

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(this.Value == "1")
   {
       FormEngineUserControl formItem = (FormEngineUserControl)this.Form.FieldControls["Other"];
       formItem.FieldInfo.CaptionStyle = "font-weight:bold";
   }
}
```

However, the field caption in the form doesn't seem to get bolded. I tried testing if the event even fires and it does. Infact, if I try something like formItem.Text = "Something" then the texbox gets filled with "Something". While debugging I also noticed that the field caption style does get changed to "font-weight: bold" but that doesn't show on the form. So, there is something wrong with the captionstyle property or the way I am using it. How do I get it to work?

(Please note that the field control "Other" is a text box input)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late in Page's lifecycle and the control has already been rendered. Try to set the CaptionStyle earlier (e.g. in control's OnLoad or OnInit) then you'll know with certainty.